# Mouse actions are not working in headless chrome? (python selenium)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

*I'm using python-selenium and Chrome...trying to automate to take a snap when the cursor moves to a particular position of my screen. When I launch the browser, it's working super fine!*

> But, If I removed "headless" argument mouse actions are working !!!

**How can I use ActionChains in headless chrome?**

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import os,time,traceback
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") 
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized") 


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname('__file__'))
DRIVER_BIN = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "bin/chromedriver")

try:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = DRIVER_BIN,options=chrome_options)
    browser.get('http://somethingurl.com')
    time.sleep(3)

    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='chartdiv']") # find part of the page you want image of
    time.sleep(1)
    action=ActionChains(browser)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(element,1020,120) #635,100
    action.perform()
    time.sleep(3)

    location = element.location
    size = element.size
    stress_report_png = browser.get_screenshot_as_png()
    browser.quit()
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    browser.quit()

stress_report_img = Image.open(BytesIO(stress_report_png)) # uses PIL library to open image in memory
stress_report_img = stress_report_img.crop((1270,330,4000,1320))  
stress_report_img.save('stress_report.png') # saves new cropped image
```

Comment: Did you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55122326/double-click-does-not-work-with-headless-selenium-in-python

Comment: NO use, its not working!